# Spring Integration: Scatter-Gather pattern implementation

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-integration

I'm developing a file parsing system with Spring Integration.

The scenario is next: 
Poller picks up files from the directory, then we apply some transformations, parsing, etc... In the end we need to store data into two sources (mongoDB and File System) and delete the original file.

I'm using Scatter-Gather pattern to perform storage operations in parallel.

Question: How can I release the group automatically? and also route aggregated results to the final handler?

Here is a code example:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow processDomainFileFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("receiverChannel") 
            .scatterGather(scatterer -> scatterer
                                .recipientFlow(m -> true, subFlow -> subFlow.handle(new DataToMongoHandler()))
                                .recipientFlow(m -> true, subFlow -> subFlow.handle(new DataToFileStorageHandler())),
                        gatherer -> gatherer
                                .releaseStrategy(group -> group.size() == 2),
                    scatterGatherSpec -> scatterGatherSpec
                            .gatherChannel(MessageChannels.direct("gateway").get()))
            .get();
}
```

and here is a final handler:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow gatewayFlow(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from("gateway")
            .handle(new DeleteOriginalFileHandler())
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `aggregator()`, configure it to release the group when the size is 2; change the subflows to send a message to the aggregator after success.

Comment: Hey Gary, Thanks for the input. I understand the principle, but can't figure out the details. I've updated my question using scatter Gather method. The release Strategy does not work out of the box. My both handlers are void. should I populate the headers manually? also I can't figure out how to redirect the aggregation result to the final handler.

Comment: Since the handlers return void, you need some other mechanism to generate the result - add a couple of pub/sub channels to the subflows, with the second subscriber on each returning a result. If the handler fails, the second subscriber won't be called (by default). You can add a timeout to the aggregator (gatherer).